# What exactly does layout_scrollFlags = "snapMargins" do?

Tags: android-layout, material-design, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

I've read the documentation of this attribute:

> An additional flag to be used with 'snap'. If set, the view will be snapped to its top and bottom margins, as opposed to the edges of the view itself.

https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/appbar/AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.html#scroll_flag_snap

But I can't observe any actual effect in my app. What margin are they talking about? Every margin on the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` (on which this attribute is set) completely destroys the layout.

Comment: It's like magnet, check out the last demo here: https://www.jianshu.com/p/7caa5f4f49bd

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's useful yet, but [here is the difference:)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnQp2.png)
If you pass **snap** as scroll flag, then it will move your view (in my case this search bar, it's linearLayout) to it's edge **NOT INCLUDING** the margin_layout

Then I've tried **snap|snapMargin** and it moved with the margin

P.S. No idea why **snapMargin** doesn't work without **snap** ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score -3):

This attribute is responsible for a scrolling behavior of AppBarLayout and its children. You can apply it directly to AppBarLayout or on the inside views, in the xml layout of your AppCompatActivity. It has to be an instance of AppCompatActivity if you want to use AppBar features. Also, the design library must be included in Gradle dependencies, like so: `implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'`

Please refer this link:-[https://medium.com/@tonia.tkachuk/appbarlayout-scroll-behavior-with-layout-scrollflags-2eec41b4366b][1]

Comment: What exactly does it do?